# Jquery Mobile splitview in iPad

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to jquery mobile . I am developing ipad app using phonegap and jquery mobile(1.0.1).
I need to add splitview for my application. I have searched in google and found **"http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/"** .

But It doesn't work for me. My question. Is there any other tutorial for splitview or better way to add **asyraf9 solution**  to my apps?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experimented with the solution from asyraf9 but it doesn't seem to work very well (and isn't that configurable either unless you want to poke around in it's source). It also hasn't been updated in many months by now.

I ended up using Sencha Touch instead which looked better and have a whole company behind it, not a single developer. It isn't a plugin for jQuery though so it doesn't use the familiar $-syntax but that also means that it probably will work fine if you want jquery for handling other stuff (like xhr). Check out a demo of their splitview and other mobile controls on the link below.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/

Comment: thanks for ur answer. But i am developing my app jquery mobile and i have developed more than 50% my app.

Comment: Ah, too bad then. Hope you find something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Splitview was done for JQM <1.0. The way it's set up, it is difficult to integrate with JQM, because it basically disables the navigation and viewport and then sets up it's own. So if you would get splitview to work, you would be bound to the single page you are working in.

If you want to try an alternative, have a look at [multiview](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/multiview/test/fix_triplePop.html)([Github](https://github.com/frequent/multiview)), which I started based on splitview, but which runs using JQM navigation. It's still work in progress, but I need for a project I'm doing, so I'm patching it up as I go along.

You will need to use my modified JQM version. There are two tweaks left inside JQM, which I ahven't been able to remove so far.

Comment: can i use this multiview jquery mobile 1.0.1? and how to hide button in main panel?

Comment: don't think so. I changed so many thing for 1.1, so the current version will not be compatible with 1.0. I don't know what's left on Github in my 1.0 folder. I had a version for 1.0, which was working alright. Try and see if it works

Comment: I am using jquery mobile 1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar. I'm using jQuery's `.load()` and it seems to work quite well

```
$('#sidepanel').load('path to file you're trying to load.html', function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
  $('#sidepanel').trigger('create'); //this applies the jquery mobile stylings to the loaded content
});
```

`sidepanel`is the container for the secondary view you want to load things into